# Need to leave for double entry china visa?

Tags: visas, china

A quick question. I have a double entry 2x60 days visa in PRC. Do I need to leave to and reenter into China to use the second entry, or can I stay for the full 120 days without leaving any time before?

Comment: What passport are you on?

Answer (score 2):

The key word is double "entry". Yes you have to leave. A 60 day visa allows you to stay in the country for a maximum of 60 days, then you have to leave.  This is pretty much the rule anywhere in the world.  On the brightside, a trip to Hong Kong or Macau counts as leaving.

Comment: Depending on where in China the OP's actual business is, at trip to Hong Kong or Macau may not be "quick".

Comment: The reference was intended to point out that Hong Kong and Macau counted as "leaving", even though they are still part of China.  I have edited out the word quick, are you happy?